# AFNetworking Upload Image Strange Response

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I'm trying to upload an image to a server using AFNetworking but i'm recieving a really strange response from server.

There is the code:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.theserver.net"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/public_html/imageUpload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[def valueForKey:@"cUsuario"]] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *response = [operation responseString];
        NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
            NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

And the PHP is:

```
function upload(){
    $uploaddir = 'public_html/go2images/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       sendResponse(200, 'Upload Successful');
      return true;
    }
    sendResponse(403, 'Upload Failed');
      return false;
}
```

The response that i'm receiving is HTML Tags like html,body...
What is going wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the "/" at the beginning of path parameter in your method multipartFormRequestWithMethod. And what is the html response from the server? It should have some helpful information.

Comment: 2013-06-04 20:55:10.655 TRNewApp[2709:907] response: [<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>

]
@verbumdei

Comment: Is the image uploaded successfully to the server?

Comment: No. No image appears on the server. @verbumdei

Comment: Try to log the server to see the lines of code executed. And see after the pho upload function if there is anything else being called or whether you use any html template.

Comment: The AFNetworking code is fine.  Have you inspected the `$_FILES` variable to see its contents?  Is the file you're uploading bigger than your server's `MAX_FILE_SIZE`?

Comment: @AaronBrager No, i was uploading using FTP and the file was ok, this is so strange...

Comment: FTP doesn't use HTTP multi-part form upload.  Perhaps your server is not configured for this type of upload.

Comment: I will search about this and try to configure my server correctly! Thanks for the tip @AaronBrager